# Manipulando imagem JS

Tags: php, javascript

Galera estou precisando de uma ajuda no seguinte ponto.
Preciso manipular uma imagem e adicionar marcações na mesma.

Exemplo:
Tenho uma imagem de uma planta de uma casa, e gostaria que o usuário selecionasse um item, exemplo, uma mesa e arrastasse até no local da planta que gostaria que a mesa estivesse. 
Um detalhe, preciso salvar depois isso no banco...

O meu problema é que não faço nem ideia de que forma poderia pesquisar sobre esse tema.
Alguém já passou por algo parecido que poderia me dar um norte para resolver esse problema.

Eu pesquisei algumas coisas sobre canvas. Mas não tive muito sucesso no problema em si...

Em outras palavras estou perdido.

Comment: Talvez o jQuery UI possa te dar um caminho: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Show, eu estava vendo ele agora mesmo... O problema está sendo manipular o objeto na imagem e depois salvar isso, exemplo, vou colocar algo sobre a imagem e preciso salvar isso pra posteriormente carregar essa imagem e mostrar o objeto exatamente na onde coloquei...

Comment: Vc vai ter que criar um formulário oculto e ir guardando os valores nele para enviar ao banco de dados.